# IndexPath.row changes when using search issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to successfully implement a UISearchcontroller into my UITableview however I have the following issues, I pass data using the indexPath.row method to the next view controller and the indexPath.row changes when I search, secondly I am using multiple arrays for my data in my tableview, and so what i've done is created another array that holds all of the other arrays content in one and searches through that, and it all works perfectly except when I want to pass my data because the indexPath.row changes instead of staying with the cell (which is what i need to happen). Please could you check out my code and see if you can help?

```
#import "AbsViewController.h"

@interface AbsViewController ()

@end

@implementation AbsViewController {

//these are all my arrays
//The arrays that carry for no equipment.
NSArray *tableData;
NSArray *thumbnails;
NSArray *sets;
NSArray *reps;
NSArray *instructions;
NSArray *materials;
NSArray *status;
NSArray *tips;
NSArray *difficulty;
NSArray *target;

//The arrays that carry for equipment.
NSArray *tableData1;
NSArray *thumbnails1;
NSArray *sets1;
NSArray *reps1;
NSArray *instructions1;
NSArray *materials1;
NSArray *status1;
NSArray *tips1;
NSArray *difficulty1;
NSArray *target1;

//The arrays that carry for bosu ball.
NSArray *tableData2;
NSArray *thumbnails2;
NSArray *sets2;
NSArray *reps2;
NSArray *instructions2;
NSArray *materials2;
NSArray *status2;
NSArray *tips2;
NSArray *difficulty2;
NSArray *target2;

//The arrays that carry for physio ball.
NSArray *tableData3;
NSArray *thumbnails3;
NSArray *sets3;
NSArray *reps3;
NSArray *instructions3;
NSArray *materials3;
NSArray *status3;
NSArray *tips3;
NSArray *difficulty3;
NSArray *target3;

//The arrays that carry for weighted.
NSArray *tableData4;
NSArray *thumbnails4;
NSArray *sets4;
NSArray *reps4;
NSArray *instructions4;
NSArray *materials4;
NSArray *status4;
NSArray *tips4;
NSArray *difficulty4;
NSArray *target4;

//Search array
NSArray *tableData5;
NSArray *status5;
NSArray *thumbnails5;

//The array for the search results.
NSArray *searchResults;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Abdominal";

//Here im initializing my arrays.
// Find out the path of my array.
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Abs" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
tableData = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
status = [dict objectForKey:@"status"];

// Find out the path of recipes.plist
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Abs1" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path1];
tableData1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"name"];
thumbnails1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
status1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"status"];

// Find out the path of recipes.plist
NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Abs2" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path2];
tableData2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"name"];
thumbnails2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
status2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"status"];


// Find out the path of recipes.plist
NSString *path3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Abs3" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path3];
tableData3 = [dict3 objectForKey:@"name"];
thumbnails3 = [dict3 objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
status3 = [dict3 objectForKey:@"status"];

NSString *path4 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Abs4" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict4 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path4];
tableData4 = [dict4 objectForKey:@"name"];
thumbnails4 = [dict4 objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
status4 = [dict4 objectForKey:@"status"];


//this is the array that carries all the content.
NSString *path5 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AbsTotal" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict5 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path5];
tableData5 = [dict5 objectForKey:@"name"];
status5 = [dict5 objectForKey:@"status"];
thumbnails5 = [dict5 objectForKey:@"thumbnails"];


}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
    return 1;
}

return 5 ;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];
}
else if (section == 0) {
    return [tableData count];
}
else if (section == 1) {
    return [tableData1 count];
}
else if (section == 2) {
    return [tableData2 count];
}
else if (section == 3) {
    return [tableData3 count];
}
else if (section == 4) {
    return [tableData4 count];
}
else {
    return [tableData5 count];
}
}

//this is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ExerciseCell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type: %@", [status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type: %@", [status1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type: %@", [status2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type: %@", [status3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 4) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type: %@", [status4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
else {

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type: %@", [status    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}


return cell;
}

//this is where i've attempted to fix the issue but didn't work.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

NSInteger rowNumber = 0;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    rowNumber += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}

rowNumber += indexPath.row;

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)rowNumber);


}

//this is where i filter my tableview
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];

searchResults = [tableData5 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar   scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];



return YES;
}

//Here i create my view for my header/
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// create the parent view that will hold header Label
UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,25)];

customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor belizeHoleColor];

UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor belizeHoleColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:14];
headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(6,0,320,25);
if (section == 1) {
    headerLabel.text =  @"";
}
if (section == 2) {
    headerLabel.text =  @"";
}
if (section == 3) {
    headerLabel.text =  @"";
}
if (section == 4) {
    headerLabel.text =  @"";
}
if (section == 0) {
    headerLabel.text =  @"";
}

headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor cloudsColor];

[customView addSubview:headerLabel];

return customView;
}
```

please if someone could help that would sooooooo appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: u mean, when u tapped on search results table, indexpath is changing

Comment: @Shan yes thats whats happening

Comment: change is due to because u tapped on searchdisplaycontroller's tableview it different than the groupedtableview

Comment: better u can pass the data directly from the array that u used for searching i,e the one combining all the arrays

Comment: i edited my answer check it out

Comment: i edited my answer check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
  //u can do this on - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath method first get 

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
      NSString *PassData = [tableData5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  //    NSString *passData = nil; //COMMENT THIS LINE SINCE IT CONTAINS SELECTED VALUE FROM SEARCH DISPLAY TABLEVIEW NO NEED TO BE ST NULL AGAIN "COMMENT THIS LINE AND TRY"
      NSString *selectedStatus = nil;
      UIImage *selectedThumbImage = nil;

  //assuming ur array's contains equal number of objects
      if([tableData containsObject:passData]) //if the search results contains an object in this array
  {
    //by using passData from search results tableview's tapped row u cn get all the below grouped tableview data now do for other array's 
    int index = [tableData indexOfObject:passData]; //get the index of selected array
    selectedStatus = [status objectAtIndex:index];  //from that index get the status data
    selectedThumbImage  = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:index];//get thumbnil image from index
  }
else if ([tableData1 containsObject:passData])
 {
    int index = [tableData1 indexOfObject:passData]; //get the index of selected array
    selectedStatus = [status1 objectAtIndex:index];  //from that index get the status data
    selectedThumbImage  = [thumbnails1 objectAtIndex:index];//get thumbnil image from index

}
else if ([tableData2 containsObject:passData])
{
    int index = [tableData2 indexOfObject:passData]; //get the index of selected array
    selectedStatus = [status2 objectAtIndex:index];  //from that index get the status data
    selectedThumbImage  = [thumbnails2 objectAtIndex:index];//get thumbnil image from index
 }
 else if (//check for otehr remaining array)
 {
  //grab all details

 }

 //at the end your passData contains title , selectedStatus contains status , and selectedThumbImage contains thumb image use it to pass 
}//end  if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

Comment: this dosen't work because searchResults is an undeclared identifier. and then how do i pass my data using this?

Comment: see u said u hav an array that contains all the array's objects rite

Comment: look at the code, i have  one array called tableData5 that draws from a plist that holds everything, i don't know how i would beable to combine all the arrays maybe you can help with that as well.

Comment: how are u searching with respect to array rite

Comment: im searhing via the - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{ method where i give searchResults array the filtered tableData5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36466/discussion-between-shan-and-user2600115)

Comment: yA SORRY, COMMENT OUT THAT   NSString *passData = nil;

Comment: SEE MY ONE MORE EDITED ANSWER SORRRY I WAS IN HURRY :)